# Fedora 16 - LXDE - dual display (monitor/head/view) - automatic shutdown

Tags: display, fedora, shutdown

I am experiencing troubles with two display in fedora 16 (LXDE). During boot time both display are working, but when system starts one display automatically shut down. It happened out of the blue. Some time before when I updated system this happened but then I booted older kernel release and everything was fine, now this did not helps.

When it used to work it looked like this:

```
[marek@dev etc]$ xrandr 
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 2560 x 1024, maximum 8192 x 8192
VGA1 connected 1280x1024+1280+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 340mm x 270mm
   1280x1024      75.0*+   60.0  
   1024x768       75.1     70.1     60.0  
   832x624        74.6  
   800x600        72.2     75.0     60.3     56.2  
   640x480        72.8     75.0     66.7     60.0  
   720x400        70.1  
HDMI1 connected 1280x1024+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 340mm x 270mm
   1280x1024      60.0*+   75.0  
   1152x864       75.0  
   1024x768       75.1     70.1     60.0  
   832x624        74.6  
   800x600        72.2     75.0     60.3  
   640x480        72.8     75.0     60.0  
   720x400        70.1  
DP1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

In past times (when it worked with older kernel) I tried to unplug the working monitor (VGA1) and leave only this that did not worked (HDMI1) to see what will happend, then this message appeared during boot and monitors shuts down "fast tsc calibration failed monitor or display problem". I did not tried it yet, should I ?

Now it looks like this:

```
[marek@dev ~]$ xrandr 
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1280 x 1024, maximum 8192 x 8192
VGA1 connected 1280x1024+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 340mm x 270mm
   1280x1024      75.0*+   60.0  
   1280x960       60.0  
   1280x800       74.9     59.8  
   1152x864       75.0  
   1280x768       74.9     59.9  
   1024x768       75.1     70.1     60.0  
   1024x576       60.0  
   832x624        74.6  
   800x600        72.2     75.0     60.3     56.2  
   848x480        60.0  
   640x480        72.8     75.0     66.7     60.0  
   720x400        70.1  
HDMI1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

Actual configuration:

```
[marek@dev ~]$ sudo cat /etc/grub2.cfg | grep menuen
menuentry 'Fedora (3.6.6-1.fc16.x86_64)' --class fedora --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os {
menuentry 'Fedora (3.6.5-2.fc16.x86_64)' --class fedora --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os {
menuentry 'Fedora (3.6.2-1.fc16.x86_64)' --class fedora --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os {
menuentry "Windows 7 (loader) (on /dev/sda1)" --class windows --class os {
[marek@dev ~]$ uname -a
Linux dev.fei.tuke.sk 3.6.2-1.fc16.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed Oct 17 05:30:01 UTC 2012 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
[marek@dev ~]$ ls  /etc/X11/xorg.conf
ls: cannot access /etc/X11/xorg.conf: No such file or directory
```

dmesg is here [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/QAwMAAjH)

AOC is VGA (that one which is working), AOC used to be HDM1 time ago (that one which is notworking now),

```
[root@dev log]# grep AOC Xorg.*
Xorg.0.log:[    27.809] (II) intel(0): Manufacturer: AOC  Model: a725  Serial#: 35948
Xorg.0.log:[    27.810] (II) intel(0): EDID vendor "AOC", prod id 42789
Xorg.0.log:[  2209.148] (II) intel(0): EDID vendor "AOC", prod id 42789
Xorg.0.log:[  2209.389] (II) intel(0): EDID vendor "AOC", prod id 42789
Xorg.0.log:[  2209.454] (II) intel(0): EDID vendor "AOC", prod id 42789
Xorg.0.log:[  2209.518] (II) intel(0): EDID vendor "AOC", prod id 42789
Xorg.0.log:[  2209.587] (II) intel(0): EDID vendor "AOC", prod id 42789
Xorg.0.log:[  2234.891] (II) intel(0): EDID vendor "AOC", prod id 42789
Xorg.0.log:[  3702.200] (II) intel(0): EDID vendor "AOC", prod id 42789
Xorg.0.log:[  4478.854] (II) intel(0): EDID vendor "AOC", prod id 42789
Xorg.0.log:[  7918.207] (II) intel(0): EDID vendor "AOC", prod id 42789
Xorg.0.log:[ 20067.874] (II) intel(0): EDID vendor "AOC", prod id 42789
Xorg.0.log:[ 20276.535] (II) intel(0): EDID vendor "AOC", prod id 42789
Xorg.0.log:[ 20279.588] (II) intel(0): EDID vendor "AOC", prod id 42789
Xorg.0.log:[ 20391.441] (II) intel(0): EDID vendor "AOC", prod id 42789
Xorg.0.log:[ 20395.051] (II) intel(0): EDID vendor "AOC", prod id 42789
Xorg.0.log:[ 20411.719] (II) intel(0): EDID vendor "AOC", prod id 42789
Xorg.0.log:[ 20423.927] (II) intel(0): EDID vendor "AOC", prod id 42789
Xorg.0.log:[ 20489.721] (II) intel(0): EDID vendor "AOC", prod id 42789
Xorg.0.log:[ 20501.000] (II) intel(0): EDID vendor "AOC", prod id 42789
Xorg.0.log:[ 20964.436] (II) intel(0): EDID vendor "AOC", prod id 42789
Xorg.0.log.old:[    23.363] (II) intel(0): Manufacturer: AOC  Model: a725  Serial#: 35948
Xorg.0.log.old:[    23.364] (II) intel(0): EDID vendor "AOC", prod id 42789
Xorg.0.log.old:[    30.197] (II) intel(0): EDID vendor "AOC", prod id 42789
Xorg.0.log.old:[    30.384] (II) intel(0): EDID vendor "AOC", prod id 42789
Xorg.0.log.old:[    30.448] (II) intel(0): EDID vendor "AOC", prod id 42789
Xorg.0.log.old:[    30.515] (II) intel(0): EDID vendor "AOC", prod id 42789
Xorg.0.log.old:[    30.820] (II) intel(0): EDID vendor "AOC", prod id 42789
Xorg.0.log.old:[    40.241] (II) intel(0): EDID vendor "AOC", prod id 42789
Xorg.9.log:[    13.439] (II) intel(0): Manufacturer: AOC  Model: a725  Serial#: 35948
Xorg.9.log:[    13.439] (II) intel(0): EDID vendor "AOC", prod id 42789
[root@dev log]# grep HP Xorg.*
Xorg.9.log:[    13.545] (II) intel(0): Monitor name: HP L1750
[root@dev log]# ls -l Xorg.*
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 70017 Nov 16 13:36 Xorg.0.log
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 43890 Nov 16 07:47 Xorg.0.log.old
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 31884 Feb 27  2012 Xorg.9.log
```

Many thanks

Comment: As it was discovered later it was probably the bug after I have updated kernel. Now it works